# Name of java design pattern

Tags: java

I want to know the name of the design pattern used in this code, thanks :

```
public class A{
    private A(){}
 private  static class AHolder{
      private  final A INSTANCE =new A(); 

 }
 public static A getInstance(){
   return AHolder.INSTANCE;
  }
 }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is popularly called Singleton design pattern structure. As Andy Turner Sir has already mentioned , it is also called lazy type Singleton pattern.